# foreach row insert foreach

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I hope someone can help me with this before I end up going crazy.

I have 3 tables:

```
Table A
SELECT
companypk,
companyname,
logo,
msscope
FROM global_companies
```

Table B

```
SELECT docpk, 
templatename, 
variation, 
doctype, 
modifydate, 
attachment, 
`scope`
FROM templates_documents
```

Table C

```
SELECT documentpk, 
companyfk, 
docref, 
doctitle, 
doctype, 
docowner, 
revision, 
issuedate, 
reasonforchange, 
status, 
attachment
FROM documents_doucments
```

None of the Tables are related.  However What I am trying to achieve is for when I add a new client, on table A, that my code looks up what scope they have in Table A, then matches that to table B, then insert relevant documents into table C.  So far here is my code:

```
//Add Template Documentation
$sql = "SELECT doctype, templatename FROM templates_documents WHERE scope = '".$values["msscope"]."'";
$rs = CustomQuery($sql); 
$results = $rs;
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
{
   "INSERT INTO documents_doucments (companyfk, doctype, doctitle) values('".$values["companypk"]."',$row[doctype], $row[templatename])";
}
```

I know that the query section works as I have tried echo-ing the results and the correct about of columns is displayed however it is not inserting anything into table C.  So far I have tried changing while to foreach.  I am also doing this from the client_after_add.php page which is why the companypk is a session field and works with other examples I have.

Any thoughts would be welcome.

Comment: Execute your `INSERT` SQL Query to perform DB operation.

Comment: OH I'm such an idiot, am kicking myself I couldnt see that, code now reads while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
{
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO documents_doucments (companyfk, doctype, doctitle) values('".$values["companypk"]."',$row[doctype], $row[templatename])";CustomQuery($sql2);
} but now getting syntax error see prntscr.com/4tkwm1 - i suspect it may because i dont have "" around destinaation fields

Comment: Could someone please tell me how to change this segment of code $row[doctype], $row[templatename] to correctly use "" inside the square brackets

Comment: wrap your all string into single quotes, like 'Quality Policy Statement', your PHP variables will wrapped into single quotes like:
`'$values[companypk]','$row[doctype]','$row[templatename]'`

Comment: Thank you that has solved it and working fine

Answer (score 1):

First you don't appear to be sending your Insert statement into the database. Merely writing a string inside a loop will do nothing to the database.

Second, you are using PHP to do functionality that should be performed in the database. You can do the SELECT and INSERT in a single statement like:

```
INSERT INTO documents_doucments (companyfk, doctype, doctitle) SELECT '".$values["companypk"]."', doctype, templatename FROM templates_documents WHERE scope = '".$values["msscope"]."'
```

Answer (score 0):

Code that worked was.

```
//Add Template Documentation
$sql = "SELECT doctype, templatename FROM templates_documents WHERE scope = '".$values["msscope"]."'";
$rs = CustomQuery($sql); 
$results = $rs;
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
{
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO documents_doucments (companyfk, doctype, doctitle) values('".$values["companypk"]."','$row[doctype]','$row[templatename]')";CustomQuery($sql2);
}
```